# convert a data frame into tensor in R

Tags: r

I have a data frame, which contain thousands of firms from year 1998 to 2007(each firm not necessarily have equal length of time duration). and I want to convert it into a tensor with index: firm, year, variables.

how to achieve this ?

I don't know how to extract a small part  of this data set to put here for us to discuss the problem, any one know how to do it?

```
structure(list(year = c(1998, 1998, 1998, 1998, 1998, 1998, 1998, 
1998, 1998, 1998, 1998, 1998, 1998, 1998, 1998, 1998, 1998, 1998, 
1998, 1998, 1998, 1998, 1998, 1998, 1998, 1998, 1998, 1998, 1998, 
1998, 1998, 1998, 1998, 1998, 1998, 1998, 1998, 1998, 1998, 1998, 
1998, 1998, 1998, 1998, 1998, 1998, 1998, 1998, 1998, 1998, 1998, 
1998, 1998, 1998, 1998, 1998, 1998, 1998, 1998, 1998, 1998, 1998, 
1998, 1998, 1998, 1998, 1998, 1998, 1998, 1998), firmid = c("QB3732337", 
"113810712", "618851819", "619457768", "HU5176905", "618024813", 
"617883552", "105679742", "230141773", "609442909", "HU6355534", 
"617882832", "60088847X", "617881725", "618403506", "145665417", 
"216582994", "14405557X", "103400293", "607369138", "617737408", 
"177160683", "142418787", "245560903", "15112238X", "617880650", 
"618354214", "226040099", "128955068", "61156047X", "617481385", 
"226091312", "190380322", "617880255", "611567073", "GD6120293", 
"617876061", "617875739", "126925703", "221461337", "614801582", 
"617883931", "618129447", "101713181", "611209524", "617883974", 
"706747835", "242727819", "608934944", "619723894", "139432377", 
"152102399", "617866832", "614407067", "607282008", "117944574", 
"617865629", "618354185", "228791275", "134789270", "113810632", 
"EJ2468142", "169832427", "115319804", "602003890", "211551128", 
"193929448", "105044755", "704448663", "21960081X"), provinceid = c(420000, 
140000, 440000, 450000, 420000, 440000, 440000, 130000, 650000, 
330000, 420000, 440000, 120000, 440000, 440000, 330000, 530000, 
330000, 120000, 310000, 440000, 410000, 320000, 230000, 340000, 
440000, 440000, 620000, 230000, 350000, 440000, 620000, 440000, 
440000, 350000, 440000, 440000, 440000, 220000, 610000, 410000, 
440000, 440000, 110000, 350000, 440000, 410000, 210000, 320000, 
450000, 320000, 340000, 440000, 410000, 310000, 210000, 440000, 
440000, 650000, 320000, 140000, 330000, 370000, 150000, 140000, 
510000, 440000, 130000, 330000, 530000), industrycode2 = c(3400, 
3500, 2900, 1900, 1500, 2200, 1400, 3600, 1500, 4000, 1500, 3000, 
2400, 2100, 1800, 1300, 2900, 4000, 3600, 2300, 1900, 3700, 2200, 
3400, 2600, 1800, 2400, 1300, 1800, 2400, 1900, 3100, 1400, 1700, 
2400, 3400, 2600, 2600, 1400, 2600, 3100, 1800, 3100, 1400, 2600, 
3300, 1300, 2200, 3000, 3100, 4100, 3000, 1500, 1400, 3500, 3500, 
3700, 2600, 2300, 3200, 1700, 4000, 4200, 3600, 2500, 1300, 3500, 
3600, 1700, 2600), sales = c(45860, 4050, 17034, 154721, 267, 
7703, 47572, 846, 267, 5132, 1767, 8354, 5668, 75330, 8935, 1958, 
154721, 13072, 10654, 40505, 20637, 1510, 12884, 10753, 45542, 
5286, 27492, 267, 1557, 872, 10892, 1386, 32054, 7290, 6903, 
8263, 6996, 12848, 460, 44823, 52000, 16353, 6225, 750, 10863, 
35110, 10638, 154721, 18100, 16773, 2415, 8686, 14362, 19831, 
46958, 1340, 79855, 61817, 1114, 154721, 7030, 9923, 599, 4060, 
154721, 361, 72986, 445, 18080, 3682), cogs = c(44780, 2430, 
13839, 144088, 246, 9310, 37863, 495, 52, 4170, 1582, 7416, 3964, 
58090, 8639, 1667, 211569, 8066, 4960, 28399, 19831, 1280, 12564, 
7540, 37058, 1855, 25519, 70, 1539, 700, 10398, 1190, 25048, 
6779, 5500, 7656, 6078, 12519, 370, 39479, 26816, 16586, 6061, 
534, 10064, 32783, 8519, 308403, 16000, 23833, 1282, 6918, 12097, 
15663, 35182, 768, 76005, 58528, 775, 4362410, 5770, 9040, 417, 
2630, 167668, 290, 64038, 306, 15898, 2511), inventory = c(2740, 
280, 1950, 46914, 711, 9552, 3984, 4989, 497, 1249, 0, 4336, 
1450, 3000, 284, 0, 134404, 5881, 9347, 4818, 1744, 377, 376, 
12238, 11669, 835, 17355, 226, 1370, 360, 434, 1089, 12154, 4000, 
2388, 7257, 1547, 808, 137, 5920, 8750, 5600, 179, 151, 1321, 
3454, 5479, 135303, 7480, 5943, 565, 850, 3032, 1207, 11307, 
474, 2574, 26104, 519, 604670, 400, 501, 106, 7040, 43568, 711, 
6763, 558, 444, 564), fixedasset = c(8580, 460, 6750, 28874, 
2878, 25901, 43081, 3065, 198, 1163, 2140, 8484, 1688, 6900, 
631, 1290, 849666, 6545, 10075, 6658, 3089, 581, 114, 22299, 
22499, 3967, 54033, 1106, 883, 435, 404, 1712, 29329, 7952, 3176, 
10272, 533, 138, 854, 14151, 64252, 10672, 5023, 62, 213, 1068, 
572, 1115119, 14090, 71451, 13017, 5390, 6657, 5840, 31943, 80, 
26145, 41905, 517, 3801800, 1164, 1725, 220, 15550, 72000, 825, 
4697, 1913, 735, 3415), totalasset = c(13610, 3220, 16090, 166501, 
14319, 44739, 78920, 10394, 823, 4698, 3101, 25325, 4221, 14900, 
3118, 1724, 1091978, 28912, 28272, 27222, 10000, 1178, 1413, 
42394, 52156, 11284, 89191, 1582, 6514, 3531, 1495, 3978, 54618, 
22352, 13733, 27088, 3247, 1450, 1164, 33419, 129957, 18000, 
20163, 266, 3728, 15286, 17337, 1718823, 25650, 94590, 15418, 
8430, 12425, 10060, 75576, 991, 46436, 75405, 1973, 5976610, 
4604, 5720, 1327, 43440, 248715, 1710, 31723, 2799, 4616, 5417
), stateshare = c(0, 1, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 1, 1, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 
1, 0.518154501914978, 1, 1, 0, 0, 1, 1, 0.699999988079071, 0.831946730613708, 
0, 0, 1, 1, 0, 0, 1, 0.200000002980232, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 
0.400013834238052, 0, 0, 0.25, 0, 0.400000005960464, 0, 1, 0, 
0, 1, 1, 0.823567152023315, 0, 0, 1, 0.742925107479095, 0, 1, 
0.661562383174896, 1, 0, 1, 1, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0.749309420585632, 
1), foreignshare = c(0.571428596973419, 0, 1, 0.385093629360199, 
0, 0.5, 1, 0, 0, 0.30011722445488, 0, 0.699992954730988, 1, 1, 
0.5, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0.300029307603836, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0.782930612564087, 
1, 0, 0, 1, 1, 0, 0.416000008583069, 1, 0.899999976158142, 1, 
1, 1, 0, 0, 0.59998619556427, 0.700012564659119, 0.233907759189606, 
0, 1, 0.600000023841858, 1, 0, 0.509767174720764, 0.299807518720627, 
0, 0, 0, 1, 0.531239151954651, 0, 0.257074922323227, 1, 0, 0.245536029338837, 
0, 0.285785287618637, 0, 0, 0.245354115962982, 0, 0.219982624053955, 
0, 0.25069060921669, 0), privateshare = c(0.428571432828903, 
0, 0, 0.614906370639801, 0, 0.5, 0, 0, 0, 0.699882745742798, 
0, 0.300007075071335, 0, 0, 0.5, 0, 0.481845527887344, 0, 0, 
0, 0.699970722198486, 0, 0, 0.300000011920929, 0.168053239583969, 
0.217069372534752, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0.38400000333786, 0, 0.100000001490116, 
0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0.299987435340881, 0.766092240810394, 0.75, 
0, 0, 0, 0, 0.490232825279236, 0.700192511081696, 0, 0, 0.176432847976685, 
0, 0.468760877847672, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0.0929015725851059, 0, 0.714214682579041, 
0, 0, 0.754645884037018, 0, 0.780017375946045, 0, 0, 0), stateown = c(0, 
1, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 1, 1, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 1, 1, 0, 0, 1, 
1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 
0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 1, 1, 
0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 1), foreignown = c(0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 
0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 1, 
1, 0, 0, 1, 0, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 
0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0), privateown = c(0, 
0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 
0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 
0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 
0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0), mixown = c(1, 0, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 
1, 0, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 
1, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 1, 0, 0, 1, 1, 0, 0, 1, 
0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0), stateonly = c(0, 
1, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 1, 1, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 1, 1, 0, 0, 1, 
1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 
0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 1, 1, 
0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 0), mixonly = c(1, 0, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 1, 
0, 1, 0, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 
0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 1, 0, 0, 1, 1, 0, 0, 
1, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0), foreignonly = c(0, 
0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 
0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 1, 1, 0, 0, 1, 0, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 
0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 
0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0), privateonly = c(0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 
0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 
0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 
0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0), gs = c(0, 
1, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 1, 1, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 1, 1, 0, 0, 1, 
1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 
0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 1, 1, 
0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 1), gm = c(1, 0, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 1, 
0, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 
0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 1, 0, 0, 1, 1, 0, 0, 1, 0, 
1, 0, 1, 0, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0), gf = c(0, 0, 
1, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 
0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 1, 1, 0, 0, 1, 0, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 
1, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 
0, 0, 0, 0, 0), privatize = c(0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 
0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 
0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 
0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0), IR = c(0.061188030987978, 
0.115226335823536, 0.140906140208244, 0.325592696666718, 2.8902440071106, 
1.02599358558655, 0.105221457779408, 3.07859539985657, 3.07859539985657, 
0.299520373344421, 0.0191550496965647, 0.584681749343872, 0.365792125463486, 
0.0516440011560917, 0.0328741744160652, 0.0191550496965647, 0.635272681713104, 
0.729109823703766, 1.8844758272171, 0.169653862714767, 0.0879431217908859, 
0.294531255960464, 0.0299267750233412, 1.62307691574097, 0.314884781837463, 
0.450134783983231, 0.680081486701965, 3.07859539985657, 0.890188455581665, 
0.514285743236542, 0.0417387969791889, 0.915126025676727, 0.485228359699249, 
0.590057551860809, 0.434181809425354, 0.947884023189545, 0.254524528980255, 
0.0645418986678123, 0.370270282030106, 0.14995314180851, 0.326297730207443, 
0.337634146213531, 0.0295330807566643, 0.282771527767181, 0.131259933114052, 
0.105359487235546, 0.643150627613068, 0.438721418380737, 0.467500001192093, 
0.249360129237175, 0.44071763753891, 0.12286788225174, 0.250640660524368, 
0.0770605877041817, 0.321385949850082, 0.6171875, 0.0338661931455135, 
0.446008741855621, 0.669677436351776, 0.138609156012535, 0.0693240910768509, 
0.0554203540086746, 0.254196643829346, 2.67680597305298, 0.259846836328506, 
2.4517240524292, 0.10560917109251, 1.82352936267853, 0.0279280412942171, 
0.224611714482307), GM = c(0.0241179093718529, 0.666666686534882, 
0.230869278311729, 0.25, 0, -0.0678684562444687, 0.256424486637115, 
0.709090888500214, 0.0769230797886848, 0.230695441365242, 0.116940580308437, 
0.126483276486397, 0.429868817329407, 0.296780854463577, 0.0342632234096527, 
0.174565091729164, 0.25985848903656, 0.620629787445068, 0.807692289352417, 
0.426282614469528, 0.0406434386968613, 0.1796875, 0.0254695955663919, 
0.426127314567566, 0.228938415646553, 0.807692289352417, 0.0773149430751801, 
-0.0678684562444687, 0.0116959065198898, 0.245714291930199, 0.0475091375410557, 
0.164705887436867, 0.279702961444855, 0.0753798484802246, 0.255090922117233, 
0.0792842209339142, 0.151036530733109, 0.0262800548225641, 0.243243247270584, 
0.135363101959229, 0.807692289352417, -0.0140479924157262, 0.0270582418888807, 
0.404494374990463, 0.0793918892741203, 0.0709819123148918, 0.24873811006546, 
0.0649604573845863, 0.131249994039536, -0.0678684562444687, 0.807692289352417, 
0.255565196275711, 0.187236502766609, 0.266104847192764, 0.334716618061066, 
0.744791686534882, 0.0506545640528202, 0.0561953261494637, 0.437419354915619, 
0.0327548310160637, 0.218370884656906, 0.0976769924163818, 0.436450839042664, 
0.54372626543045, 0.595140397548676, 0.244827583432198, 0.139729529619217, 
0.454248368740082, 0.137249961495399, 0.466348081827164), CI = c(0.630418837070465, 
0.142857149243355, 0.41951522231102, 0.173416376113892, 0.200991690158844, 
0.578935623168945, 0.545881927013397, 0.294881671667099, 0.240583226084709, 
0.247552156448364, 0.690099954605103, 0.335004925727844, 0.399905234575272, 
0.463087260723114, 0.202373310923576, 0.748259842395782, 0.778098106384277, 
0.226376593112946, 0.356359660625458, 0.24458159506321, 0.308899998664856, 
0.493208825588226, 0.0846758112311363, 0.52599424123764, 0.431378930807114, 
0.351559728384018, 0.605812251567841, 0.699115037918091, 0.135554194450378, 
0.123194560408592, 0.270234107971191, 0.430367022752762, 0.536984145641327, 
0.355762362480164, 0.231267750263214, 0.379208505153656, 0.164151519536972, 
0.0951724126935005, 0.733676970005035, 0.423441767692566, 0.494409680366516, 
0.59288889169693, 0.24911966919899, 0.233082711696625, 0.0846758112311363, 
0.0846758112311363, 0.0846758112311363, 0.648768961429596, 0.549317717552185, 
0.755375862121582, 0.780426323413849, 0.639383137226105, 0.535774648189545, 
0.580516874790192, 0.422660619020462, 0.0846758112311363, 0.563032984733582, 
0.555732369422913, 0.262037515640259, 0.636113107204437, 0.252823621034622, 
0.301573425531387, 0.165787488222122, 0.357965022325516, 0.289487957954407, 
0.482456147670746, 0.148062914609909, 0.683458387851715, 0.159228771924973, 
0.63042277097702), WACC = c(0.0587803088128567, 0.114285714924335, 
0.0474829077720642, 0.089603066444397, 0, -0.0595453642308712, 
-0.0409021787345409, 0.00990956369787455, -0.0255164038389921, 
0.0834397599101067, 0.00515962578356266, -0.00363277364522219, 
0.0127931768074632, 0.175039649009705, 0.0102629894390702, -0.00986078940331936, 
-0.00165113247931004, 0.0121057005599141, 0.0084889642894268, 
0.175039649009705, -0.0706999972462654, 0.000848896452225745, 
0.0481245554983616, 0.0177619475871325, -0.00661477027460933, 
-0.0334987565875053, -0.0147324288263917, -0.095448799431324, 
0.00445194961503148, 0.0218068547546864, 0.0675585269927979, 
0.0175967831164598, 0.0445274449884892, -0.00881352834403515, 
0.0546129755675793, -0.0589929111301899, 0.0344933792948723, 
0.0675862058997154, 0.0180412363260984, 0.028426943346858, 0.0992020443081856, 
-0.016499999910593, -0.0906611084938049, 0.0338345877826214, 
-0.103832200169563, 0.0640455335378647, 0.0919997692108154, -0.002492984989658, 
0.0179337225854397, -0.103832200169563, -0.035867165774107, 0.0543297752737999, 
0.0449094548821449, 0.120576545596123, 0.0157457403838634, -0.0847628638148308, 
0.0742096677422523, -0.00257277372293174, 0.0309173855930567, 
0.0231686513870955, 0.116203308105469, 0.0748251751065254, 0.11379050463438, 
-0.024171270430088, 0.00290694180876017, -0.0760233923792839, 
0.166220098733902, 0.0178635232150555, 0.175039649009705, 0.0304596647620201
), Salesgrowth = c(NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, 
NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, 
NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, 
NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, 
NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, 
NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, 
NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, 
NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, 
NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, 
NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, 
NA_real_, NA_real_), Export = c(0, 0, 0.998237371444702, 0.726109445095062, 
0, 0.00252844509668648, 0.895112693309784, 0, 0, 0.0362807661294937, 
0, 0.348896056413651, 1, 0.88113659620285, 0.868606626987457, 
0, 0, 0, 0.0201816353946924, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0.195195838809013, 
1, 0.926722705364227, 0, 0, 0.743137240409851, 1, 0, 0.0486678741872311, 
0.944032907485962, 0.501250028610229, 0, 0.999022483825684, 0.996436417102814, 
0, 0, 0, 0.988813638687134, 0, 0, 1, 0.967754900455475, 0, 0, 
0, 0.00271074729971588, 0, 0, 0.0384709499776363, 0, 0.0599414147436619, 
0, 0, 1, 0, 0.000741015828680247, 0, 0.870000004768372, 0, 0, 
0.905181586742401, 0, 0.599265575408936, 0, 0.931351482868195, 
0), Leverage = c(14.4659090042114, 0.483870953321457, 0.5306316614151, 
5.99260854721069, 21.3162212371826, 0.802828848361969, 1.31172561645508, 
2.2685534954071, 0.796943247318268, 1.39327561855316, 2.87625002861023, 
1.1588100194931, 0.973352015018463, 0.183956876397133, 0.769580006599426, 
0.289454013109207, 5.48250532150269, 0.52344822883606, 0.197103783488274, 
0.183956876397133, 0.570105195045471, 3.6015625, 3.71000003814697, 
4.99886798858643, 5.34887409210205, 1.4610687494278, 0.733816742897034, 
1.18206894397736, 21.3162212371826, 1.80238091945648, 1.5820380449295, 
3.65263152122498, 0.705373585224152, 0.914846241474152, 0.916945815086365, 
1.07761931419373, 0.183956876397133, 0.361502349376678, 2.07936501502991, 
2.1812469959259, 0.760839521884918, 3.46650123596191, 1.53558850288391, 
0.330000013113022, 3.10121011734009, 0.874662756919861, 1.48345506191254, 
1.28475737571716, 1.05200004577637, 7.94806528091431, 0.203309133648872, 
1.210857629776, 1.16275024414062, 2.03012037277222, 0.476988017559052, 
0.45521292090416, 1.75912058353424, 0.23635022342205, 0.342176884412766, 
0.406383603811264, 0.641940057277679, 1, 1.0321592092514, 0.459677428007126, 
3.95616054534912, 4.42857122421265, 1.85715568065643, 3.64950156211853, 
0.515927731990814, 0.516942024230957), Current = c(0.642147123813629, 
0.260168313980103, 0.600883364677429, 0.956995725631714, 0.260168313980103, 
1.23653173446655, 1.40639424324036, 1.07675218582153, 0.260168313980103, 
0.801113069057465, 2.81943321228027, 0.843509554862976, 1.13398694992065, 
0.260168313980103, 0.545235216617584, 2.81943321228027, 1.19198870658875, 
0.474293291568756, 0.260168313980103, 0.260168313980103, 0.401427298784256, 
1.21140944957733, 0.326404929161072, 1.71450614929199, 0.987657248973846, 
1.09765684604645, 1.29162395000458, 1.80042016506195, 0.98863410949707, 
0.73352712392807, 0.839596688747406, 1.08649599552155, 0.746986508369446, 
0.519444465637207, 0.607772707939148, 0.260168313980103, 0.260168313980103, 
0.293445110321045, 2.21290326118469, 0.673032999038696, 0.964383006095886, 
2.21746039390564, 0.470989525318146, 0.323529422283173, 1.15627562999725, 
0.506606042385101, 0.626914441585541, 1.53568696975708, 1.02733683586121, 
2.81943321228027, 1.05705952644348, 1.7860734462738, 1.1391396522522, 
2.3782639503479, 0.665584921836853, 0.340285390615463, 1.23362839221954, 
0.490639895200729, 0.345467031002045, 0.696641504764557, 0.268895357847214, 
0.741701245307922, 0.433604329824448, 0.887159526348114, 1.37459933757782, 
0.593891382217407, 0.616396367549896, 2.4796838760376, 0.42551463842392, 
0.725274741649628), Cover = c(0.649999976158142, 0.112769484519958, 
0, 0.5163214802742, NA, -0.111111111938953, 0.976295828819275, 
1, -0.461538463830948, 0.249363869428635, 0, -1.61016952991486, 
0, 0.0135302441194654, 0.161290317773819, -0.396551728248596, 
-1.61016952991486, 1.04938268661499, 0.804794549942017, -0.00240922393277287, 
-0.0130399344488978, 0, 0.267605632543564, 0.831447958946228, 
1.6728972196579, 0, -0.00519031146541238, 0, -0.0773333311080933, 
0.862068951129913, -0.0281690135598183, 0.32051283121109, 0.332811266183853, 
0, 0.304878056049347, 0, 0, 0, -0.0192307699471712, 0.822123885154724, 
0.376334100961685, -0.10884353518486, -0.86366331577301, 0, -0.0272628143429756, 
0.403465360403061, -0.00689655169844627, -0.935179531574249, 
1.6728972196579, 0, -0.215469613671303, 0.818540453910828, 0.538461565971375, 
0, 0.861155688762665, 0.0506329126656055, 0.00725478818640113, 
0.204545453190804, -0.0206896550953388, 0.640307724475861, 0.0638686120510101, 
0.584474861621857, -0.0592105276882648, 0, 0, -0.1875, 0.520370066165924, 
0, 0.020833333954215, 0.528301894664764), Bank = c(1, 1, 0, 1, 
0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 1, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 1, 0, 1, 1, 1, 
0, 1, 0, 1, 1, 0, 1, 1, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 1, 1, 
0, 1, 1, 0, 1, 1, 1, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 
0, 1, 1), Inctaxrate = c(0.321428567171097, 0.330000013113022, 
0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0.200000002980232, 
0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0.333333343267441, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0.266666680574417, 
0.121365360915661, 0, 0.122222222387791, 0, 0, 0, 0.333333343267441, 
0.333333343267441, 0.0750062316656113, 0, 0, 0.111111111938953, 
0, 0.120408162474632, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0.279069781303406, 0.244000002741814, 
0, 0, 0, 0.33002045750618, 0, 0, 0.0624906569719315, 0.330000013113022, 
0, 0.324999988079071, 0, 0.149377599358559, 0, 0.0553662702441216, 
0, 0, 0.113207548856735), ROA = c(0.0205731075257063, 0.0931676998734474, 
0.0474829077720642, 0.0433390773832798, 0, -0.0661615133285522, 
-0.0800430849194527, 0, -0.0328068025410175, 0.0625798180699348, 
0.00515962578356266, -0.0123593285679817, 0.0127931768074632, 
0.15384615957737, 0.0070558050647378, -0.0232018567621708, -0.00898461323231459, 
0.000345877138897777, 0.00017685342754703, 0.15384615957737, 
-0.0723000019788742, 0.000848896452225745, 0.0346779897809029, 
0.000424588390160352, -0.050157219171524, -0.0334987603127956, 
-0.0147996991872787, -0.095448799431324, 0, 0.000566411763429642, 
0.0688963234424591, 0.011312217451632, 0.0289648100733757, -0.00881352927535772, 
0.0327677838504314, -0.0589929111301899, 0.0344933792948723, 
0.0675862058997154, 0.0171821303665638, 0.000628385052550584, 
0.061758890748024, -0.0173888895660639, -0.126888483762741, 0.0338345877826214, 
-0.126888483762741, 0.0320554748177528, 0.0926342532038689, -0.00428083632141352, 
0.00701754400506616, -0.107918381690979, -0.0434557013213634, 
0.00510083045810461, 0.0201207250356674, 0.120576538145542, 0.00154811050742865, 
-0.0807265415787697, 0.0736712887883186, -0.00233406270854175, 
0.0324379131197929, 0.0111919632181525, 0.108601219952106, 0.0300699304789305, 
0.120572723448277, -0.024171270430088, 0.00290694157592952, -0.0900584831833839, 
0.074015699326992, 0.0178635232150555, 0.15384615957737, 0.00978401303291321
), ROS = c(0.00610553845763206, 0.0740740746259689, 0.0448514744639397, 
0.0400644056499004, 0, -0.384265869855881, -0.132788196206093, 
0, -0.482142865657806, 0.0572876073420048, 0.00905489549040794, 
-0.0374670810997486, 0.00952717009931803, 0.14293497800827, 0.00246222713030875, 
-0.0204290095716715, -0.0368077680468559, 0.000764993892516941, 
0.000469307298772037, 0.14293497800827, -0.0350341610610485, 
0.000662251666653901, 0.00380316679365933, 0.00167395151220262, 
-0.057441484183073, -0.0715096518397331, -0.0480139665305614, 
-0.681996643543243, 0, 0.00229357788339257, 0.00945648178458214, 
0.032467532902956, 0.0493542142212391, -0.0270233191549778, 0.0651890486478806, 
-0.193392232060432, 0.0160091482102871, 0.00762764643877745, 
0.0434782616794109, 0.000468509475467727, 0.14293497800827, -0.0191402193158865, 
-0.527710855007172, 0.0120000001043081, -0.0867163762450218, 
0.013956137932837, 0.14293497800827, -0.0224030781537294, 0.00994475092738867, 
-0.608597159385681, -0.277432709932327, 0.00495049497112632, 
0.0174070466309786, 0.0611668601632118, 0.00249158823862672, 
-0.0597014911472797, 0.0428401492536068, -0.00284711318090558, 
0.0574506297707558, 0.014846958220005, 0.0711237564682961, 0.0173334684222937, 
0.14293497800827, -0.25862067937851, 0.00270326854661107, -0.426592797040939, 
0.0321705527603626, 0.112359553575516, 0.0831858441233635, 0.0143943512812257
), num_ID = c(110811, 5231, 56906, 57829, 109353, 53870, 53447, 
3268, 31728, 44842, 109431, 53437, 35768, 53429, 55421, 12707, 
28753, 12371, 2213, 40407, 52997, 20414, 11831, 32734, 13940, 
53414, 55153, 30755, 8398, 47905, 51851, 30780, 23354, 53407, 
48003, 107459, 53394, 53390, 7955, 29718, 51021, 53453, 54348, 
597, 46440, 53454, 62729, 32489, 43867, 57861, 11030, 14104, 
53370, 50914, 39352, 5956, 53364, 55151, 31386, 9852, 5230, 106943, 
18825, 5561, 36645, 27786, 24240, 2994, 61769, 29396)), .Names = c("year", 
"firmid", "provinceid", "industrycode2", "sales", "cogs", "inventory", 
"fixedasset", "totalasset", "stateshare", "foreignshare", "privateshare", 
"stateown", "foreignown", "privateown", "mixown", "stateonly", 
"mixonly", "foreignonly", "privateonly", "gs", "gm", "gf", "privatize", 
"IR", "GM", "CI", "WACC", "Salesgrowth", "Export", "Leverage", 
"Current", "Cover", "Bank", "Inctaxrate", "ROA", "ROS", "num_ID"
), datalabel = "", time.stamp = "25 Sep 2016 11:04", formats = c("%9.0g", 
"%9s", "%9.0g", "%9.0g", "%12.0g", "%12.0g", "%12.0g", "%12.0g", 
"%12.0g", "%9.0g", "%9.0g", "%9.0g", "%9.0g", "%9.0g", "%9.0g", 
"%9.0g", "%9.0g", "%9.0g", "%9.0g", "%9.0g", "%9.0g", "%9.0g", 
"%9.0g", "%9.0g", "%9.0g", "%9.0g", "%9.0g", "%9.0g", "%9.0g", 
"%9.0g", "%9.0g", "%9.0g", "%9.0g", "%9.0g", "%9.0g", "%9.0g", 
"%9.0g", "%9.0g"), types = c(65527L, 9L, 65527L, 65527L, 65526L, 
65526L, 65526L, 65526L, 65526L, 65527L, 65527L, 65527L, 65527L, 
65527L, 65527L, 65527L, 65527L, 65527L, 65527L, 65527L, 65527L, 
65527L, 65527L, 65527L, 65527L, 65527L, 65527L, 65527L, 65527L, 
65527L, 65527L, 65527L, 65527L, 65527L, 65527L, 65527L, 65527L, 
65527L), val.labels = structure(c("", "", "", "", "", "", "", 
"", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", 
"", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", ""), .Names = c("", 
"", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", 
"", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", 
"", "", "", "", "")), var.labels = c("", "<b7><a8><c8><U+02F4><fa><c2><eb>", 
"", "", "<b2><fa><U+01B7><cf><fa><ca><db><ca><d5><c8><eb>", "<b2><fa><U+01B7><cf><fa><ca><U+06F3><U+0271><be>", 
"<b4><e6><bb><f5>", "<b9><U+0336><a8><d7><U+02B2><fa><ba><U+03FC><c6>", 
"<d7><U+02B2><fa><d7><U+073C><c6>", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", 
"", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", 
"", "", "", "", "", "group(firmid)"), version = 118L, label.table = list(), expansion.fields = list(), byteorder = "LSF", row.names = c(NA, 
70L), class = "data.frame")
```

data added, now I know I can change a three modes array into a three modes tensor, so we could also consider how to change the current data frame to a three modes array with dimensions "firmid","year",and "all other co-variates except these two"

Or image a three dimensions reference system X-Y-Z, I want X to be firms, Y to be co-variates, Z to be years

any suggestions?

Comment: Please give a minimal [reproducible example](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269/how-to-make-a-great-r-reproducible-example)

Comment: ...use `dput(head(df,n=10))` or whatever

Comment: Or `dput(droplevels(head(df, 10)))`... as suggested at Cristobal's link.